# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hammerjs'

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I updated my Angular 2 CLI project from `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` via `ng init`. My project uses Angular `2.0.0-rc.5` and Angular Material `2.0.0-alpha.7-4` but when run with `ng serve` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hammerjs' in '/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 38:0-18
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

ERROR in [default] /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@angular2-material/core/gestures/MdGestureConfig.d.ts:4:39 
Cannot find name 'HammerManager'.

ERROR in [default] /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@angular2-material/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts:67:19 
Cannot find name 'HammerInput'.

ERROR in [default] /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@angular2-material/slider/slider.d.ts:50:19 
Cannot find name 'HammerInput'.

ERROR in [default] /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@angular2-material/slider/slider.d.ts:52:24 
Cannot find name 'HammerInput'.
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To work-around this bug, temporarily add `hammerjs` to your project:

```
npm install hammerjs --save
npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
```

and import in your module definition:

```
/** TODO: remove when work-around is not needed*/
import 'hammerjs';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    // ...
```

Comment: Exactly after these steps that error appeared which is in the topic. That's why I've come here..

Comment: @godblessstrawberrythis was too long time ago to remember.

Answer (score 15):

I was facing issue

```
npm uninstall hammerjs --save
```

then `npm install hammerjs@latest`

solved my problem

hammerjs latest installed version is 2.0.8
Angular is  5.2.11

Comment: Same problem updating a ionic 5 app from angular 11 to angular 12.
This solution solved the issue.
Thanks!