# Error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic material angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Error adding angular material in project

```
ERROR in
node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(136,20):

error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.

node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(154,104):

error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic
```

I'm trying to install material design but it looks like that's the issue.

Environment settings: `Angular CLI: 1.7.4 & Node: 9.11.1`

Comment: There is [**a bug logged in github against `@angular/material`**](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11100) for exactly this. For us to help you, you should show us your _whole_ `package.json`, though I suspect the response in the bug I linked will solve your problem. FYI The version of node you run is largely irrelevant for this kind of problem because packages specify which engine version they can run on.

Answer (score 29):

The best way here is to change all your material dependencies to match that of angular for those of you who have angular 5.2.0 follow this

INITIAL

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.1",
  "@angular/material": "^6.0.1"    
}
```

just change these to whatever the current version of the other angular components are.

FINAL

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/material": "^5.2.0"    
}
```

THEN do `npm install`

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you @moze king. You saved my day. – karunakar bhogyari just now   edit

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

This occurs when all of your angular packagage in one version and material package in another version.

I faced this when my angular package version was 5.2 and material version was 6.0
so i changed the material version back to 5.1 and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

OK, here is how I fixed it:
Step one:

- run `npm update -D` and `npm update -S`
  But I don't think this was necessary, because the problem was stil there.

Step tow:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
ng update
```

The Command complainded that I needed to run (so I did):

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

After trying: `ng serve` I got an error since 'hammerjs' was not installed, so I run (but this might not be your case):

```
npm install hammerjs --save
```

and 
`npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev`

I don't understand the point of --save-dev, but I did it this way. Its compiling now.

This last hammerjs thing has been found here:
[Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hammerjs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496267/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-hammerjs)

Hope this help.

Comment: I also run "npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk", from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885008/i-am-new-to-angular-i-just-installed-angular-material-and-angular-animations-in

But I think this was because another issue.

Comment: Again, its alot of commands, but it's the way I found to update everything else and not need to downgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issues but downgrading my @angular/material to version 5.0 worked.
You can try that out.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a mismatch in your angular version and material version.
To see the error go to package.json file where you can find the angular version and the material version.

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.2.1",              //ERROR here the version is 6.x
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^6.2.1",         // ERROR here the material version is 6.x
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"}
```

},

As you can see in the above package.json file there is mismatch of the version.
There are two ways to solve this error:

1. Upgrade your angular by using command:  **ng update** (*this will change your angular versio to 6.x*).
2. Change the version of cdk and material to **5.2.0 manually** then enter the command: **npm install** *this will add the material of version 5.2.0*

Answer (score -1):

Maybe its related to angular 1.6 that just came out ?

I have the same problem, but just can't figure out how to update the reste of it (instead of downgrade one thing, upgrade everything else thing), but I can't figure it out.

Tried `npm update -D` and than `npm update -S` But it did not help.

That idea came from: [I am new to angular. I just installed angular material and angular animations in my small project and got some of the errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885008/i-am-new-to-angular-i-just-installed-angular-material-and-angular-animations-in)